# How to use multiple SELECT statement in INSERT statement and also in CONCAT() function

Tags: mysql

I'm working on  a project where i want to insert data from another table and also use select statement in  concatenate function but i can't understand ?

```
INSERT INTO c_order
 (oid,cid,servicename,servicetype,servicecategory,price,address,date,status,time)
VALUES
  ('qw121','121',(select servicename,servicetype,price, from inner_subservice where inssid=1),(select building,city,pincode CONCAT(building,'',city,'',pincode) as fullname from address where cid='121',now(),'ongoing',null);
```

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from inner_subservice where inssid=1),(select building,city,pincode CONCAT(build' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO c_order(oid,cid,servicename,servicetype,servicecategory,price,address,date,status,time)
VALUES("qw121","121",
(select servicename,servicetype,price from inner_subservice where inssid=1),
(select building,city,pincode, CONCAT(building,'',city,'',pincode) as fullname from address where cid='121'),now(),
'ongoing',null);
```

You were missing some parenthesis and you had some extra comas there. Apart from those this query should work fine.

Comment: Your insert fields are less than your values. Make sure they are the same number. I guess you don't need 'ongoing',null values (the last two).

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO c_order(oid,cid,servicename,servicetype,servicecategory,price,address,date,status,time) VALUES("qw121","121",(select servicename,servicetype,servicecategory,price from inner_subservice where inssid=1),(select CONCAT(building,'',city,'',pincode) as fullname from address where cid='121'),now(),'ongoing',null);
```

Couldn't comment on pr1nc3's answer because i don't have enough rep, but his query needed a small tweak and hopefully this would work.
Instead of selecting building, city and pincode from address you only need to select the concat() result of the respective fields. Also you didn't select servicecategory field.